# M2DOC how to define a variable and use it

Tags: m2doc

I would like to define a new variable in my template : m:var:lang with the value fr to specify the language.
I do this in the properties of my wordx, but how to use it in the template ?

{m:lang} doesn't work.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Start by using it in your template:

{m:lang}

Save your template and open the [template properties wizard](https://www.m2doc.org/ref-doc/nightly/#template-properties-wizard). On the variable page of the wizard:

[image: variable page]

You should see a "lang" varaible without type. Set the type of your variable using the "Edit" button. For instance use the type String and click "Finish".

Note that you will need to add a value to your .genconf file for this variable. You can use the [generation configuration wizard](https://www.m2doc.org/ref-doc/nightly/#generation-configuration-wizard).